# SOS: "Parameters and Events Issue" with SDK2 NOT with SDK1

Tags: javascript, php, soundcloud

**[#SDK2 Parameters and Events Issue]** 
Can you please help me with this, please.

SoundCloud Username: `hotitv`

Why is that i can't make it any option (volume, onfinish, autoplay) work for "`SC.stream`" in SDK 2 (sdk-2.0.0.js) and it work perfectly on SDK 1 (sdk.js) with the same code. Any clue why is this happening?

**Code:**

```
SC.stream(track.uri, {autoPlay: false, onfinish:playNextSound}, function (stream) {

(...)

});
```

> [Full Code (Line 674, 790, 910):](https://github.com/marcoscolina/player/blob/master/wp-hoti-player-functions.php)

Marcos

hoti